# pydotplus is not working correctly, descision-tree visualizaion errior?

Tags: python, graphviz, graph-visualization, pydot

Actually I'm using sklearn for visualizing decision tree. I have already installed graphviz and pydotplus and also set the environment variable of graphviz but when i run this code, it gives an error.

I'm using "kyphosis" dataset.

Here is the actual code

```
from IPython.display import Image
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import pydotplus

features = list(df.columns[1:])
features

Output:
['Age', 'Number', 'Start']
```

it works fine

but when i run this below code.
Code:

```
dot_data = StringIO()  
export_graphviz(dtree, 
out_file=dot_data,feature_names=features,filled=True,rounded=True)

graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
Image(graph[0].create_png())
```

It shows an error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-44-28715c87781f> in <module>
      3 
      4 graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
----> 5 Image(graph[0].create_png())

TypeError: 'Dot' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `[0]` from `Image(graph[0].create_png())`.

It shall work fine.

You'll be able to visualize your decision tree.